# Can't install quantstrat for R on R version 3.3.3 on MacOS Sierra

Tags: r

Am trying to run this for installing quantstrat on my mac:

```
install.packages("blotter", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

However, am getting a whole load of errors:

---

> ```
> Warning in install.packages :
>   dependency 'blotter' is not available
>
> trying URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/quantstrat_0.9.1739.tar.gz'
>
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 797162 bytes (778 KB)
> ==================================================
> downloaded 778 KB
>
> During startup - Warning messages:
> 1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
> 2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
> 3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
> 4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
> ERROR: dependency 'blotter' is not available for package 'quantstrat'
> * removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/quantstrat'
> Warning in install.packages :
>   installation of package 'quantstrat' had non-zero exit status
> ```

---

Is this purely due to the `blotter` dependency? How can I download the `blotter` package, as it doesn't seem available for `R 3.3.3` also?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because quantstrat build-fail at R-Forge, you can't get the pre-build file(.tar.gz). You can get the code from github and build by yourself.

```
install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)
install_github("braverock/blotter") # dependency
install_github("braverock/quantstrat")
```